# Increase font size when using 'openair' package to draw wind rose diagram?

Tags: r, font-size, openair

I'm having difficulties changing font sizes in the wind rose diagram produced by the `openair` package. The `windRose` plots all right. But the documentation for the package does not seem to specify how to change the font sizes for the title, labels and ticks.

```
par(cex.lab=, cex.axis=, cex.main=, cex.sub=)
```

doesn't seem to work either.

Does anyone know a way to enlarge the font sizes? Your help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is a reproducible example of what I am trying to plot:

```
library(openair)
df<-read.csv('http://www.openair-project.org/CSV/OpenAir_example_data_long.csv')
windRose(df)
```

[image]

Comment: I added a reproducible example of what you are trying to plot.

Answer (score 5):

I was searching for a similar answer for polarPlot and was able to adjust the font size with this parameter

```
polarPlot(...,par.settings=list(fontsize=list(text=18)))
```

I imagine

```
windRose(df,par.settings=list(fontsize=list(text=18))))
```

would work in your case. See `trellis.par.get()` for other parameters